# Dart file copy in Windows

Tags: file-io, dart

The `File` class in the `dart:io` library doesn't yet include `copy()` and `move()` methods.

To tide me over until they arrive, I'm trying to roll my own copy function.  I'm using the code below on Windows, but it just creates a 0kb file.

```dart
void copyFile(String input, String output) {
  var inFile = new File(input), outFile = new File(output);
  if (outFile.existsSync()) outFile.deleteSync(); // I realize this isn't required
  var inStream = null, outStream = null;
  try {
    inStream = inFile.openInputStream();
    outStream = outFile.openOutputStream(FileMode.WRITE);
    inStream.pipe(outStream);
  } finally {
    if (outStream != null && !outStream.closed) outStream.close();
    if (inStream != null && !inStream.closed) inStream.close();
  }
}
```

I've also tried replacing the `pipe` line with `print(inStream.read(100).toString());` and I get `null`.  The input file does exist (otherwise I'd get a FileIOException).  Am I doing something wrong, or are input streams broken under Windows?

I'm using:

- Dart Editor version 0.3.1_r17463
- Dart SDK version 0.3.1.2_r17463

**Edit:** The following works (although it doesn't "chunk").  Am I using the streams above incorrectly?

```dart
void copyFile(String input, String output) {
  var inFile = new File(input), outFile = new File(output);
  if (outFile.existsSync()) outFile.deleteSync(); // I realize this isn't required
  outFile.writeAsBytesSync(inFile.readAsBytesSync(), FileMode.WRITE);
}
```

Comment: I think the problem may be that I'm trying to access the stream synchronously?  Maybe my code above closes the stream before data arrives?

Answer (score 2):

With your first code snippet, you get an empty file because `pipe` is not a synchronous method. Thus, the copy of inputStream to outputStream has not started when the finally block is execute. By closing the streams in this finally block, you stop the `pipe` before it even starts. Without that finally block the copy is done correctly.

```dart
void copyFile(String input, String output) {
  final inStream = new File(input).openInputStream();
  final outStream = new File(output).openOutputStream(FileMode.WRITE);
  inStream.pipe(outStream);
}
```

Finally, you don't have to worry about closing streams because `pipe` close streams by default once achieved. See [InputStream.pipe](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/bleeding_edge/dart_io/InputStream.html#pipe).

Comment: Does that mean anything I want to be done after the copy must be placed in a Future (e.g. `.then()`)?  How is one to do this if pipe() doesn't return a Future?  Do I need to add "event handlers" to my stream objects?  (_Sorry if I got the terminology wrong; still getting used to Dart semantics_).  Any way to do this synchronously?

Answer (score 2):

For synchronous copy, use:

```dart
File(sourceFile).copySync(destinationFile);
```

For asynchronous copy, use:

```dart
File(sourceFile).copy(destinationFile);
```